# AngularJS ng-show and ng-hide does not change state after $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show dynamically the `REST` respont data after an `AngularJS` `$http.get()` call. The answer arrives fine The data bindings `{{showOrderStateTrigger}}` and `{{orderDetails}}` inserted just for test purposes after the call display `true` and the expected contents. But the `ng-show` and `ng-hide` does not recognize that their condition changed. I created `ng-show` and `ng-hide` cases just to test two approaches. Checking that the variable `undefined` or a boolean variable state. I tried the `$scope.$apply()` call, but it just made the things worse. The nested calls caused exceptions. Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myApp = angular.module( "myApp", [] );
            myApp.controller( "myController", function( $scope, $http ) 
            { 
              $scope.showOrderDetailsTrigger = false;
              $scope.showOrderDetails = function ( id )
              {
                  $http.get( "/WebApplication1/orders/" + id + ".json" )
                       .then( function ( response ) {
                           $scope.orderDetails = response.data;
                           $scope.showOrderDetailsTrigger = true; } );
              }
            } )
        </script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="order" items="${orders}">
                <li ng-click="showOrderDetails( ${order.id} )">${order.name}</li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>

        <div>{{showOrderDetailsTrigger}}</div>
        <div>{{orderDetails}}</div>

        <div ng-show="{{showOrderDetailsTrigger}}">
            <div>ID: {{orderDetails.id}}</div>
            <div>Name: {{orderDetails.name}}</div>
        </div>

        <div ng-hide="{{orderDetails === undefined}}">
            <div>ID: {{orderDetails.id}}</div>
            <div>Name: {{orderDetails.name}}</div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many directives like `ng-show` , `ng-hide` and `ng-if` expect expressions that resolve truthy or falsy not interpolation expressions

try changing

```
ng-show="{{showOrderDetailsTrigger}}"
```

to

```
ng-show="showOrderDetailsTrigger"
```

For more advanced conditions would be something like:

```
ng-if="somVar != 3 && foo=='bar'"
```

Comment: Uhhh. That's right. Trivial "mistyping" fault caused by careless accuracy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worrries. is not always intuitive. Newer angular 2+ is more consistent

Comment: @Bitman In your case, you really should consider using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`. `ng-if` removes the template from the view, `ng-show` only hides it. You will have orderDetails evaluated to undefined that will lead to an error

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe I don't thing so. After the first click it should appear and stay in that state. It should show always the contents of the very last clicked list item.

Comment: @Bitman I still do think so. Your code should throw an error as far as id does not exist on undefined. `ng-if` won't change you app's behaviour

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe shouldn't throw any error.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe I works fine for me for multiple clicks as well! :)

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe AngularJS Expressions are **forgiving**. In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties generates `ReferenceError` or `TypeError`. In AngularJS, expression evaluation is forgiving to `undefined` and `null`. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Comment: @georgeawg ok, my bad ;-)